# How to Google + Style Text Input Expanding Box

Tags: facebook, text, input, google-plus

In G+ and Facebook, when you click the text input box (for updates) it will expand and give you more options. For example a submit button or another text input field.

For the life of me I can't find what to call this so that I can view some premade css3/jquery plugins/tutorials.

This is the closest I could find, but its not exactly what I am looking for.
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use normal javascript/jquery to hide/show what you want Example

```
<form><table><tr><td><lable id='lab'><input style='display:none' type='text' id='name'></input></label></td></tr></table></form>
```

AND HERE YOUR JS

```
$(function(){


$("#lab).click(function(){

$(this).css("display","none");

$("#name").css("display","block");
}
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook actually does it by loading another CSS stylesheet via AJAX, but here's a regular Javascript function that does the trick:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showDiv() {
                var area = document.getElementById("inputbox");
                area.style.height = "80px";
                var div = document.getElementById("hiddendiv");
                div.style.display="block";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="inputbox" onfocus="showDiv()" style="height:30px;">Put focus on me...</textarea>
        <div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none;">to show me!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a name for this function? So that I can research more advanced/different ways?